# ffmpeg - Stretch 4:3 video to 16:9

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video track that is a 4:3 video with pillarboxing/black bars on the side making it a 16:9 video. The resolution of the video is 960x540 (16:9).

How would I remove the blackbars and then stretch it to 16:9 to be a proper 16:9 video?

What I have:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

I'm assuming I want to use a -vf "crop=720:528:120:6" to remove the black bars from the side and the small one at the bottom, but how would I then stretch that to 16:9?

By the way, im hoping to end up with this video in the resolution: 960x540, meaning with the small 6 pixel removal of the small border under the video, im hoping to stretch that BACK to 540 from 534.

Comment: How were you able to determine the crop dimensions?

Answer (score 3):

Add a scaler after the crop.

```
-vf "crop=720:528:120:6,scale=960:540,setsar=1"
```

The setsar is added to prevent players squashing the video during playback.

Comment: I think this can work for my scenario as well, however my MP4's resolution is 1280x720 and there's no black bar at the bottom as with Ma Dude's. I'm afraid I'm a beginner with FFMPG; could I impose upon you to ask for a translation to the entire command to use?

Comment: Ask a new Q showing your tried command and its full log.

Comment: OK, got it. Will do.